# Responsive, 3 colums in deskview and 2 in mobile veiw

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

How to scale the 3 colums into two when the user has a mobile. I can a alot about media queries but I dont know how to do this. Like this:

http://postimg.org/image/sox89ekqj/

Comment: Please don\t try to use stackoverflow for your own business. please remove advertisement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to give you 2 examples on how you can do this, because there is many ways to achieve what you want.

#### using `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px
}

@media(max-width:480px){
div {
  width: 50%
}
div:last-child {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

#### using `display:inline-block`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
section {
  font-size:0
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 200px
}

@media(max-width:480px){
div {
  width: 50%
}
div:last-child {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

### EDIT

#### a possible solution with `margin`s due to OP's comment.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
section {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 204px;
}
div {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 32%;
  height: 200px
}
div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}
@media(max-width:480px){

div {
  width: 49%
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. Can you update it and tell us how to add some margin between the divs when using this method? Usully you float the left one to the left and the right one to the right. But how to do this if I firts have 3 colums and then 3? Thank you very much. @dippas

Comment: Thank you so much. Please upvote the question so more people find your good answer! @dippas

Answer (score 0):

Using Twitter Bootstrap, this is how it's done

Define your sections for the desktop version for 3 columns, using `col-**-4`, then use `col-**-6` for mobile. When the total columns goes beyond 12, it will wrap everything over column 12 to a new line.

Comment: But I want to do it by myself. Sorry dude